# Turning music into an image

Tags: c, image, music

I was bored, so I wrote something that could turn .wav files in to .bmps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char bmp[12000029]; // Need 12000028 bits, 1 pixel is 3
                    // bits and table is 28 (1500^2 * 3 + 28)

int main() {

  bmp[0]  = 0x42;   // Bitmap signature
  bmp[1]  = 0x4D;   // 'BM'

  bmp[2]  = 0x1C;   //
  bmp[3]  = 0x1B;   // Size of bitmap
  bmp[4]  = 0xB7;   // in bytes
  bmp[5]  = 0x00;   //

  bmp[10] = 0x1A;   // Image data location

  bmp[14] = 0x0C;   // Size of header

  bmp[18] = 0xDC;   //
  bmp[19] = 0x05;   // Dimensions of image
  bmp[20] = 0xDC;   // 1500 * 1500
  bmp[21] = 0x05;   //

  bmp[22] = 0x01;   // Something
  bmp[24] = 0x18;   // standard (?)


  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("file.wav", "rb");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening 'file.wav'\n");
    return 1;
  }
  for (int i = 41; i < 12000043; i++) {     // Actual music data starts at 41
    bmp[i - 15] = fgetc(fp);                // Store first data to bmp[26] (41 - 15)
  }
  fclose(fp);


  fp = fopen("file.bmp", "w+");
  for (int i = i; i < 12000028; i++) {
    fputc(bmp[i], fp);
  }
  fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

I know this is probably the most random thing ever, but it is quite intriguing in my opinion.

[image: Rick Astly - Never Gonne Give You Up]

(You just got Rickroll'd).

Comment: The reverse is also fun: Pipe some arbitrary file into sour sound device. Highly compressed file formats produce mostly white noise but files with some structure sound interesting. I recommend listening to the libc.  PDFs and SQLite database files are also nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Strange loop initialization

Hm, what's up with this loop initialization?

> ```
>   for (int i = i; i < 12000028; i++) {
> ```

`i` is not even defined at this point. Write it the non-confusing way:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 12000028; i++) {
```

#### Magic number 12000028

The number 12000028 and 12000028 + 1 and 12000028 + 15 appears in multiple places in the code. It would be better to `#define` and reuse.

```
#define BMP_SIZE 12000028

char bmp[BMP_SIZE]; // Need 12000028 bits, 1 pixel is 3
// ...

int main() {

    // ...

    for (int i = 26; i < BMP_SIZE; i++) {
        bmp[i] = fgetc(fp);
    }

    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < BMP_SIZE; i++) {
        fputc(bmp[i], fp);
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### Error checking

You checked nicely the result of opening the input file `file.wav`.
But then, why didn't you do the same for the output file `file.bmp`?

#### Use `puts` instead of `printf` when possible

When you print plain text ending with newline and you don't need to print variables, then `puts` is better than `printf`.
So instead of:

```
printf("Error opening 'file.wav'\n");
```

This is slightly better:

```
puts("Error opening 'file.wav'");
```

#### Usability

The input and output filenames are hardcoded.
That makes this difficult to use.
It would be great to take them as command line arguments

#### Suggested implementation

Applying the above suggestions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BMP_SIZE 12000028

char bmp[BMP_SIZE]; // Need 12000028 bytes, 1 pixel is 3
// bits and table is 28 (1500^2 * 3 + 28)

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    bmp[0]  = 0x42;   // Bitmap signature
    bmp[1]  = 0x4D;   // 'BM'

    bmp[2]  = 0x1C;   //
    bmp[3]  = 0x1B;   // Size of bitmap
    bmp[4]  = 0xB7;   // in bytes
    bmp[5]  = 0x00;   //

    bmp[10] = 0x1A;   // Image data location

    bmp[14] = 0x0C;   // Size of header

    bmp[18] = 0xDC;   //
    bmp[19] = 0x05;   // Dimensions of image
    bmp[20] = 0xDC;   // 1500 * 1500
    bmp[21] = 0x05;   //

    bmp[22] = 0x01;   // Something
    bmp[24] = 0x18;   // standard (?)

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("usage: %s input.wav output.bmp\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    char * input = argv[1];
    char * output = argv[2];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(input, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening %s for reading", input);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 26; i < BMP_SIZE; i++) {
        bmp[i] = fgetc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(output, "w+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening %s for writing", output);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < BMP_SIZE; i++) {
        fputc(bmp[i], fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop initialization is a mistake, it originally contained another value, I just messed up removing it. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: `Need 12000028 bits` -> `Need 12000028 bytes` I think?

Comment: @njzk2 true, that comment comes from the original code, I just copy pasted and overlooked in the suggested implementation. Thanks for spotting, I fixed it now